# How to install tensorflow 2 gpu on windows 10 with conda?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, anaconda, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I have Nvidia RTX 2070 and want to make use of GPU programming. I have installed Cuda the easy way through Conda but somehow the tensorflow is not detecting any GPU device. My tensorflow version is 2.3.0.

I have already tried using the following command on anaconda prompt but no luck.

`conda create --name tfgpu python=3.8.5 tensorflow-gpu`

I have also tried the longer version of downloading the CUDA toolkit and the cudnn file and copy pasting the files. but nothing seems to work. When I run the following command, I always get 0.

`print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`

Really need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this guide for installing TensorFlow and testing, also be sure to download and install latest cudnn and Cuda libraries from Nvidia's official site.
https://towardsdatascience.com/guide-to-conda-for-tensorflow-and-pytorch-db69585e32b8