# Why conda cannot install tensorflow gpu properly on Windows?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, conda, nvidia

I was using Linux at work and am used to install tensorflow GPU version via Conda.

The Linux machine has NVIDIA driver, and nvidia-smi runs properly.

The command I use is

```
conda install python tensorflow-gpu
```

Magically, conda takes care of everything. It installs cudatoolkit or whatever related tools. Once I run python in that virtual environment, GPU is usable.

Now I switch to work on Windows. The Windows box has NVIDIA driver, and nvidia-smi runs properly. Then I use the same conda command as I used on Linux. `conda install` is successful but the python in the virtual env does not detect GPU.

[How to install tensorflow 2 gpu on windows 10 with conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65710494/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-gpu-on-windows-10-with-conda) says on Windows I must manually install cudnn and Cuda. Why conda on Windows does not take care of it as Linux one does?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much expertise with how conda works as I have manually downloaded and configured tensorflow with CUDA and cuDNN.

To answer your question I'd recommend going through this blog, [Setting up Tensorflow-GPU with Cuda and Anaconda on Windows](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-and-anaconda-onwindows-2ee9c39b5c44). Here, the person uses different commands from what you've mentioned. There are a few extra steps involved as well.